# cron job failed to run

Tags: linux, bash

Retrieval of graphics card sales information

```
#!/bin/bash
curl=$(which curl)
RTX3060="http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3060"
RTX3070="http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3070"
RTX3080="http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3080"
RTX3090="http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3090"
RX6700="http://0.0.0.0:5000/rx6700"
function output_(){
 $curl $RTX3060 $RTX3070 $RTX3080 $RTX3090 $RX6700 > sales.txt
}
output_
```

and my cron job that should run every minute from november to december

```
#!/bin/bash
*/1 * * nov-dec *  /user/bin/bash /sells_Cards/sold.sh
```

I can't understand why the job it's not running by itself, I have to type the ./sold.sh in order to run the script.

The idea is that I have to create a script that takes as entry an API (the sales per minute of the largest graphics card vendors) and as an output the number of grapihic cards sold on each minutes( rtx3060, rtx3070, rtx3080, rtx3090 et rx6700) the results should be stored in a sales.txt file. I have created a directory under home named sells_Cards (/home/ubuntu/sells_Cards) and under this directory the sales.txt and the script sold.sh.
I used crontab -e  to create the job as mentioned above.

Please help me to find the pb(by the way I dont know a lot(only few) of bash scripting)Thanks in advance

Comment: In no Linux (or comercial Unix) I've worked with in the past `/user/bin/bash` would have existed. Might that be your problem?

Comment: so I should remove it or what, how about this   */1 * * nov-dec *  /sells_Cards/sold.sh

Comment: Check where bash actually lives - there's no `/usEr` directory.  Also there shouldn't be a `#!/bin/bash` in crontab - won't do any harm because it's a comment, it just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I used which bash command    and   the result  is      /usr/bin/bash.  and Ill try to remove the #!/bin/bash   and see. and thank you anyway

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash` is not the same as `/user/bin/bash` ... more specifically ... `usr` is not the same as `user`; also, if the script (`sold.sh`) has the correct shebang then there's no need to preface the script invocation with an explicit reference to the same shell (`/bin/bash` or `/usr/bin/bash` in this case); and generally speaking ... verify your various references actually exist ... do each of the following show said file exists: `ls /user/bin/bash`, `ls /usr/bin/bash`, `ls /bin/bash`

Comment: the only two exist are  /usr/bin/bash  and   /bin/bash

Comment: Now the job is working, I can see the refresh of the http requests. thanks a lot. But, it still one problem that, I have to retrieve all the result on each minutes in the file, whixh not the case. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` accepts only 1 url in the command line

```
Usage: curl [options...] <url>
```

so you need something like this (an array would be much better though)

```
output_() {
 {
     $curl $RTX3060
     $curl $RTX3070
     $curl $RTX3080
     $curl $RTX3090
     $curl $RX6700
 } > sales.txt
}
```